# How to import PageTarget class from puppeteer

Tags: typescript, puppeteer, typescript-typings

https://github.com/oliverdunk/puppeteer-extension-experiments/issues/1#issuecomment-1586292675

I want to use the PageTarget class defined in puppeteer, which is a subclass of the Target abstract class, but I can't import it.

```
import { PageTarget } from 'puppeteer'
```

error occurs, `Module '"puppeteer"' has no exported member 'PageTarget'.`

is typescript.

Comment: Why do you need to import it? What are you trying to accomplish? [There's often a better way, if you can provide context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

Answer (score 0):

You can't import `PageTarget` because it is an internal class, as per [the codebase](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/06cacfa9c1d5b185ce41a337abf94cfa8726b4f2/packages/puppeteer-core/src/cdp/Target.ts#L196):

```js
/**
 * @internal
 */
export class PageTarget extends CdpTarget {
  #defaultViewport?: Viewport;
  protected pagePromise?: Promise<Page>;
  ...
```

However, someone discusses an [alternative method](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3718#issuecomment-451325093) to get this information in a GitHub issue thread, if it isn't specifically the class that you're looking for:

```js
const pageTarget = this._page.target(); //save this to know that this was the opener
await resultItem.element.click(); //click on a link
const newTarget = await this._browser.waitForTarget(target => target.opener() === pageTarget); //check that you opened this page, rather than just checking the url
const newPage = await newTarget.page(); //get the page object
// await newPage.once("load",()=>{}); //this doesn't work; wait till page is loaded
await newPage.waitForSelector("body"); //wait for page to be loaded
```